# Yum/dnf error (35) when using https connections on CentOS Stream 9

Tags: centos, yum, ssl, dnf

BLUF: Can someone help me set yum and/or dnf to prefer TLS 1.3 when connecting to https sites?

Situation:

- fresh installation of CentOS Stream 9 (CentOS-Stream-9-20220718.0-x86_64-dvd1.iso)
- on corporate network with a transparent proxy service
- with the repos set default yum and dnf fails to download with the following error:

> Error: Failed to download metadata fro repo 'baseos': Cannot prepare
> internal mirrorlist: Curl error (35): SSL connect error for
> https://mirrors.centos.org/metalink?repo=centos-baseos-9-stream&arch=x86_64&protocol=https,http
> [error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled]

- with other repos that use https connections i am getting the same errors
- once the centos.repo is modified to point to http rather than https the downloads work
- other repos that only support https (i.e. https://download.docker.com) still do not work
- curl https://google.com results in the same error along with any up-to-date https site
- curl --tlsv1.3 https://google.com results with the correct output from the server.

I think I have tracked this problem down to a TLS 1.3 client support, possibly due to our company proxy rejecting the TLS 1.2 cyphers. What I cannot figure out is how to tell yum, dnf, or any other client side command to use TLS 1.3 to negotiate the connection.  I have found similar problems with CentOS 7 and 8 but have not found how it is addressed in 9. In 7 and 8 it seems that the openssl is missing the cyphers for TLS 1.3 but on 9 openssl is updated and has 1.3 support.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tlsv1.3` option to `~/.curlrc`. You can find other supported config file locations in the [curl manual](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html).

Forcing TLS 1.3 disabled TLS inspection in my case, but it will not work with old servers. Another option is to allow unsafe legacy renegotiation by setting UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation option in `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`:

```
…
[ crypto_policy ]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
.include = /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config
…
```

You can also set minimum supported TLS version in openssl.cnf, but it seems to be ignored by curl:

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1.3
TLS.MinProtocol = TLSv1.3
```